# Search index feature for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, search

Is there a search index-like feature for Windows?

Something that indexes your files so that you can search though them quickly later.

Comment: "Microsoft Silverlight is a programmable web browser plugin that enables features such as animation, vector graphics and audio-video playback..."

it has nothing to do with indexing/searching files

Comment: This is a non-question, sorry to say it but I think this should be closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like 'Everything'.
http://www.voidtools.com/

Very quick, very low on resources!

Answer (score 13):

You're referring to [Windows Desktop Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx). This is for XP and it's built into Windows Vista and 7

Another alternative is [Google Desktop Search](http://desktop.google.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that is a lot faster and less resource heavy (though can't index *file content*[1]), then Locate32 is a great alternative, it is a GUI pseudo-port of the unix locate command (comes in 32 and 64bit versions, is actively developed and is very small and portable):

http://locate32.net/content/view/14/26/

Windows Desktop Search, at least before version 4 in my testing was very poor performance-wise compared to Google Desktop Search. As I understand it, Microsoft have improved performance in the latest version.

---

[1] You can however in the advanced search options, find text within a set of files, but this doesn't use a pre-indexed database...

Answer (score 1):

I really like [regain](http://regain.sourceforge.net/) for Windows. It's German, but it is really good. I like it, because it indices all files you want and you can develop own filters, etc.

One problem exist: The priority of the indexing process is setup to `Normal` so it disturbs you. I contacted the developer, but there's no reaction yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Cathy](http://www.mtg.sk/rva/) search utility.

[image]

Searching cataloged local hard drive and/or offline filesystems (network shares, CD/DVDs) is almost instant. The memory footprint tiny and the exe itself is under 48K.

Main download: http://www.mtg.sk/rva/Cathy.zip . Because updating the indexes or "catalogs" is manual (which turns out to be a nice feature performance-/portability-/versioning-wise), there's a companion command-line version to script/schedule updating the index http://www.mtg.sk/rva/CathyCmd.zip

Answer (score 0):

[neoSearch](http://www.koshyjohn.com/software/neosearch/) is a desktop search program that can index your entire system in less than a minute.

**Features:**

- Indexes your computer in a matter of seconds
- Presents you with dynamic results that keep changing as you type in your query.
- Presents you with a full list of files that match your query (when the search button is clicked or 'Enter' is pressed) in as little as 0.01 seconds.
- Lets you quickly navigate to any file or folder on your system using Super-Navigation.
- Tiny hard-drive footprint and RAM usage (1.5MB).
- Paths to be included and excluded can be explicitly specified.
- Indexing can be scheduled and can also be run on demand.
- Can be set to start with your system and can be launched from the tray icon later.